# Laravel Query Builder - Sum Where and Sum Where

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have a table called stock_movements:

```
| product_id | type | qty  |
|------------|------|------|
| 1          | A    | 2    |
| 1          | A    | 1    |
| 1          | A    | 7    |
| 1          | B    | -2   |
| 1          | B    | -4   |
| 1          | B    | -1   |
| 2          | A    | 2    | 
| 2          | A    | 1    |
| 2          | A    | 7    | 
| 2          | B    | -3   | 
| 2          | B    | -3   |
| 2          | B    | -1   |
```

I am trying to create a collection of the products where which have the values of the sum of A and sum of B.

i.e. 
Group by products, type
Sum qty for each type

The key thing is that it is a collection against the product, which is the bit I am struggling with. Does anyone have any advice?

So far I have got...

```
    return $this->stockMovements()->groupBy('product_id')
        ->selectRaw('sum(qty), product_id')
        ->where('type', $this->type)
        ->get();
```

But this does not split out for types A and B.

Comment: maybe group by type?

Answer (score 4):

You need a basic pivot query, which would look something like this in Laravel:

```
return $this->stockMovements()
        ->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS sum_a, ".
                    "SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS sum_b, product_id")
        ->groupBy('product_id')
        ->get();
```

I removed the `WHERE` clause, because your data only seems to have two types, and there isn't much sense in restricting that.  If you really want the sum of quantity for just A or B, then we can write a much simpler Laravel/MySQL query.

Comment: This works, thanks. However it also returns results where the sum for both sum_a and sum_b is 0. Is there a way to exclude these ones?

Comment: @AdamLambert Yes use `->having('sum_a','>', 0)->having('sum_b','>', 0)`, or use `->havingRaw('SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) > ?', [0])`

Answer (score 1):

Using A Raw Expression

```
  $result = DB::table('stock_movements')
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(qty) as sum_qty, type'))
                ->groupBy('type')
                ->get();
```

**Rule of thumb for the use of aggregation functions in the SELECT clause**.

> If a select block does have a GROUP BY clause, any column
>   specification specified in the SELECT clause must exclusively occur as
>   a parameter of an aggregated function or in the list of columns given
>   in the GROUP BY clause, or in both.

For more details : 
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=664143&seqNum=6